# FaceBook Graph Api Webhook feed

Tags: java, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I subscribed to feed in the graph api webhook and I am receiving updates to my callback url as a charm, the issue is that I receive updates for each action that happens on the posts: likes, comments.. etc

I want to receive updates only if new post added to the wall, please advice ?

Do we have any fileds on the received json to my callback URL can I use to differentiate if this new post or a comment on a post ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the `item` field, there you'll find the item the update belongs to.

In your case ("new posts added to the wall") you have to filter for `post` in your code. Additionally you have to check the `verb`, because you get updates on edit and delete, too.

Comment: Great!! thanks bro @Norbert , one more thing
when I print out the request reader in my app engine servlet to see the json I received from the FB graph api , I note that I am always see the demo json , like below , why I dont receive the real json ? please advice 


{"entry": [{"changes": [{"field": "feed", "value": {"post_id": "44444444_444444444", "sender_name": "Test Page", "sender_id": "1067280970047460", "item": "status", "verb": "add", "published": 1, "created_time": 1502093917, "message": "Example post content."}}], "id": "0", "time": 1502093917}], "object": "page"}

Comment: I am retrieve the json in my servlet like this 

' StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader br = req.getReader();
        String str;
        while( (str = br.readLine()) != null ){
            sb.append(str);
        }

        log.info("RECEIVED NEW POST : " + sb.toString());'

Comment: I use this line, but this should not be the problem `final String body = req.getReader().lines().reduce("", (accumulator, actual) -> accumulator + actual);` Do you get only the demo json and don't receive anything other or do you print out the demo json and receive something different?

Comment: Yes ,resp.setContentType("application/json");
        String str;
        while( (str = br.readLine()) != null ){
            sb.append(str);
        }
        log.info("RECEIVED NEW POST : " + sb.toString()); 

in my app engine console log I see always 
RECEIVED NEW POST : {"entry": [{"changes": [{"field": "feed", "value": {"post_id": "44444444_444444444", "sender_name": "Test Page", "sender_id": "1067280970047460", "item": "status", "verb": "add", "published": 1, "created_time": 1502094761, "message": "Example post content."}}], "id": "0", "time": 1502094762}], "object": "page"}

Comment: Perhaps you should put your code in a gist, so I can read it completely and in a better format :) https://gist.github.com/